# How to get all root elements with a base xpath, not including children

Tags: appium, appium-android

Where I have one list item in a `ListView` it has xpath

```
/hierarchy/...LinearLayout
```

And when there are more than one, the xpath changes to

```
/hierarchy/...LinearLayout[1]
/hierarchy/...LinearLayout[2]
```

So to get all list items, I do

```
List<WebElement> els = driver.findElementsBy(By.xpath(baseXpath+"//*"));
```

There are `3` list items but `els` has a size of `12`, because each list item has `4` children.

How can I get only direct parent elements and not children such that the size of `els` is `3`, preferably in one query?

Answer (score 0):

Like this, without `+"//*"`

```
List<WebElement> els = driver.findElementsBy(By.xpath(baseXpath));
```